# Button border color xamarin forms not showed

Tags: android, xaml, button, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to set border color to button in Xamarin Forms but with this code doesn't work:

```
<Button Text="Test" 
        BorderWidth="5" 
        BorderRadius="2" 
        BorderColor="Red">
</Button>
```

Using this code the border doesn't appear.

> I've also tried [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/23039/button-bordercolor-not-showing-on-android-4-4) but doen't work.
>
> I've tried it in Android 4.4 (Phisical Device) and in Android 6.0
>   (Virtual Device) but doesn't work too.
>
> SOLVED FOLLOWING [THIS](https://fabiosilvalima.net/2016/11/21/button-border-and-radius-in-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: The link to your solution is broke. Can you post what your solution was?

Comment: If I remember well you have to add background color to button.

Answer (score 3):

There are two BottonRenderers in Xamarin Android.

1. ButtonRenderer under [`Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/ButtonRenderer.cs) namespace.
2. ButtonRenderer under [`Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/ButtonRenderer.cs) namespace.

The BottonRenderer did not achieve drawing button border where under `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat` namesapce.

The MainActivity  is inherited `FormsAppCompatActivity` rather than `FormsApplicationActivity` where is used in android project by default. So the renderer is under `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat` namesapce. But it did not achieve drawing button border.
If you want draw button border, you can custom render by using `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android` namesapce.

Answer (score 2):

By default the border width is zero, so setting its color makes no difference. You need to set both of them:

```
<Button Text="Jenson" BorderColor="Red" BorderWidth="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Samsung s3 (API 19,Android 4.4 Kitkat).
This does actually work on my phone

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyProject.MyPage" BackgroundColor = "White">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation = "Vertical" BackgroundColor = "White">

            <Button 
                Text="Test" 
                BorderWidth="10" 
                BorderRadius="5" 
                BorderColor="Red"
                    TextColor = "Black"
                    VerticalOptions = "Start"
                    HorizontalOptions = "Fill"
                BackgroundColor = "White">
            </Button>
        </StackLayout> 


    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

In cs file

```
MyPage()
{
InitializeComponent();
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I have tested a button with backgroudcolor white and it worked this is why i asked.. But i dont do it in xaml file..

Comment: Is your button in a content page?

Comment: Did you try creating the button in .cs file? Because i dont see why it doesnt work..

Comment: i solved using the link added in question, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue where I have specified the border color property alone. Looks like by default the border width is zero therefore the button border was not shown. After updating border width, it works fine.